# Website, SFTP, SSH in home directory for multiple users

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, apache2, ftp

I need a little help with configuring Ubuntu Server 14.04, apache2 and SFTP for multiple separate users. Every user needs to have website in his home directory, for example: `/home/user/public_html` available using `http://user.mydomain.com`. Also every user must be able to make SFTP and SSH connection but access must be restricted to `/home/user`. I don't know if it matters but all users will be using php, mysql and git on their accounts.

I've tried a lot of tutorials to achieve what I need but none of them worked for me. Every time when one thing works well other breaks :/

I will be grateful for any kind of help with this. Links, documentation, books are welcome.

Comment: I feel it's better to tell what you tried and what didn't work rather than asking for a one size fits all solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered adding the users who need access to the www-data group? I am fairly certain that apache runs as www-data on Ubuntu 14.04. If you add the users to this group you wont have to mess with chmod on that folder - which always has the potential to break apps that are currently in use.

Answer (score 0):

hi for me working in this way, first you need add users to a group "sftpgroup", later modify

```
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and edit add this to config file

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -f AUTH -l VERBOSE
Match Group sftpgroup
ChrootDirectory %h
ForceCommand internal-sftp
AllowTcpForwarding no
```

later modify for write and access

```
sudo chown root /home/bob
sudo chmod go-w /home/bob
sudo mkdir /home/bob/writable
sudo chown bob:sftpgroup /home/bob/writable
sudo chmod ug+rwX /home/bob/writable
```